# Creating S3 bucket in CLI: signaturedoesntmatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to create S3 bucket using command line I am having this error:

> an error occurred(signaturedoesntmatch) when calling the createbucket operation:the request signature we calculated doesn't match the signature you provided.check your key and signing method.

I have tried changing the key secret access key 2 times. Still having the same issue. Do not what else to do

Comment: Are you doing this with the AWS CLI? Where are you running the command -- on your own computer, or on an Amazon EC2 instance? How have you provided credentials to that computer, and are you sure that they are correct?

Comment: I m running this command in putty on my computer

Comment: If you are using PuTTY to connect to an EC2 instance, then the best way to assign credentials is to attach an IAM Role to the EC2 instance. Is this what you have done? Or have you stored credentials locally on the computer with `aws configure`?

Comment: I stored the credentials locally on the computer with aws configure i even creare new IAM user its keep giving me same error.

Comment: I m a student and try to pass this certification and got stuck here

Comment: It says check your key and signing method

Comment: I am still confused. Are you using PuTTY to connect to an EC2 instance, and the error message is coming from the EC2 instance? Does the instance have an IAM Role assigned to it?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when your AWS credential set using environment variables and AWS-CLI will use those values instead of value provided via configuring aws profile(~/.aws/credentials).